# $f$ is analytic in the unit disc and $f(z)=f(z^2)$ for every $z\in D(0,1)$. Prove that $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I thought about finding a series of numbers that converges in the unit disk.
and showing that bot $f(z)$ and $f(z^2)$ relate to that

cant really think of one,

any suggestions?

Comment: Think about the Maclaurin series.

Answer (score 5):

Since $f$ is continuous, and $f(z) = f(z^{2^n})$ for all $n$, we have that
$$
  f(z) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(z) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f\left(z^{2^n}\right) = f\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} z^{2^n}\right) = f(0)
$$
for all $z$ with $|z| < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Because of analyticity, if we take $f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_iz^i$, then $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_iz^i=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_iz^{2i}$. By comparing the coefficients, it follows immediately that $a_{2i}=a_i$ (and thus $a_{2^ij}=a_j$ for $i\in\mathbb N$ and $j$ odd) and $a_{2i+1}=0$. Thus all coefficients except for $a_0$ are zero, so $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Pick some $a \in D(a,1), a \neq 0$. You can pick $a=\frac{1}{2}$ for example.

Set $C:=f(a)$.

Then $$f(a)=f(a^2)=f(a^4)=f(a^8)=...=f(a^{2^n})=...=C$$
which shows that the analytic functions $f$ and $C$ agree on the convergent sequence $a^{2^n} \to 0$.

By the identity theorem, $f=C$.